# Data assignment to Kotlin VAL variable

Tags: kotlin

I am wondering whether data is inserted into the data field of SHttpJson in the following SourceCode.

```
1. MainActivity.kt

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            callSearch()
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
        fun callSearch(){
            val params = SHttpParam()
            val jsonReq = SHttpJson("authenticator", "searchAuthenticators")
            jsonReq.setData("applicationId", "test")
            params.json = jsonReq
    
        }
    }

2. SHttpJson.kt

    class SHttpJson {
        private var service: String? = null
        private var operation: String? = null
    
        private val data: HashMap<String, String>? = HashMap()
        //private var data: HashMap<String, String>? = HashMap()
    
        constructor(service: String?, operation: String?) {
            this.service = service
            this.operation = operation
        }
    
        constructor()
    
        /**
         * @param
         */
        fun setData(map_key: String, map_value: String): SHttpJson {
            data!![map_key] = map_value
            return this
        }
    }

3. SHttpParam.kt

    class SHttpParam() {
        var json = SHttpJson()
    
    }
```

When debugging in'params.json = jsonReq', you can check the data as shown in the picture below.
[When data field is val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTQqE.png)

As in the picture,'A' does not contain "data":"testData". But in B, you can see that data is included.

If the data field of SHttpJson is modified to var, it is as shown in the picture below.
[When data field is var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pgse.png)
You can see that "data":"~" is inserted in C.

If SHttpJson's data is val, isn't it that B's data field can't be inserted as well?
If the above situation is normal, I am curious about the difference between A and B.
Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: The code you give does not compile.  (`SHtpJson`'s constructor does not take any parameters, nor does it define a `setData()` method.)  I'm guessing you've cut this down from running code, but that makes it hard to follow or to relate to the linked images.

Comment: @gidds sorry my answer was late.
I tried to modify it so that it is possible to compile.